# Callback function if Vaadin Image src changes and update on client is complete

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using Vaadin 23 and I build an application which shows different images which are changed and loaded on runtime. I need the exact display size of the image to update other information based on the size. The server from which I get the image is quite slow, therefore it can last up to 10 seconds until the new image is downloaded by the client.

Image doesn't have a function like:

```
myImage.addSrcChangedAndClientUpdatedListener(...);
```

Is there any other solution to get a callback function in Java when the src Attribut changes and the new image is downloaded from the client?

My workaround is to wait 10 seconds and then get the image size by an async Javascript call.

But sometimes the image is ready after 2 seconds -> my implementation waits 8 seconds unnecessaryly which leads to bad customer experience.

Sometime the image download even takes 20 seconds -> my implementation doesn't work.

I don't see a proper solution. Any ideas? Can a implement a custom Java callback function based on custom Javascript code? How would such a solution look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Flow's `Element` API you can create a listener for the `load` DOM event that an `img` element fires after it has finished loading the image data. Using the element API you can also add several details to the event data that should be sent to the server. Here is a simple example that allows switching images, and then logs the image's size from the server:

```java
public class ImageView extends Div {
    private static final String IMAGE_1 = "https://imgs.search.brave.com/bjAqtSxNjNFNHm384o53EB6Zrv85eGtWpmspBqc98Yk/rs:fit:592:225:1/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly90c2Uy/Lm1tLmJpbmcubmV0/L3RoP2lkPU9JUC5X/ZzNXajk1SDl6VTNw/SzNMY2dwT2xRSGFG/NyZwaWQ9QXBp";
    private static final String IMAGE_2 = "https://imgs.search.brave.com/v5uhvAoiVtMDM8UPI8vk8XMELrIRKW1fVLkRsiuqnU0/rs:fit:844:225:1/g:ce/aHR0cHM6Ly90c2Ux/Lm1tLmJpbmcubmV0/L3RoP2lkPU9JUC5O/OEV3U1psZlNZNmph/cmR1cm4xckZBSGFF/SyZwaWQ9QXBp";

    public ImageView() {
        Image image = new Image();

        Button setImage1 = new Button("Set image 1", e -> image.setSrc(IMAGE_1));
        Button setImage2 = new Button("Set image 2", e -> image.setSrc(IMAGE_2));

        Span imageData = new Span();
        image.getElement().addEventListener("load", loadEvent -> {
                    JsonObject eventData = loadEvent.getEventData();
                    Number width = eventData.getNumber("element.clientWidth");
                    Number height = eventData.getNumber("element.clientHeight");
                    imageData.setText(String.format("Width: %s | Height: %s", width, height));
                })
                .addEventData("element.clientWidth")
                .addEventData("element.clientHeight");

        add(image);
        add(new Div(imageData));
        add(new Div(setImage1, setImage2));
    }
}
```

Reference:

- [Flow Element API - Listening to User Events](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/element-api/event-listener)
- [Window: load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: Where can I see all available event data Strings like `element.clientWidth` or in other cases also for events like `event.xyz`? Is there anywhere a list of all properties for `element` and `event`?